# Mapping Streams in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm trying to map a stream from Firestore into a list in Flutter. I can retrieve the data successfully, but when I pass it to the StreamBuilder it receives null.

```
Stream<List<String>> getTeamMembers(String idSquadra) {
    var res = teamsCollection.where('idSquadra', isEqualTo: idSquadra).snapshots().map(_playerNamesFromSnapshot);
    return res;
  }

  List<String> _playerNamesFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snap) {
    DocumentSnapshot doc = snap.documents[0];
    var info = doc.data['infoGiocatori'];
    var res = info.map((i) => "${i['nome']} ${i['cognome']} (${i['displayName']})");
    print('res: $res');
    return res;
  }
```

Here res correctly shows as `res: (Mario Rossi (MR1), Luigi Verdi (LV2))`, but when I try to access it in the view, I get `data: null`

```
return StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: dbService.getTeamMembers(dbService.currentUser.idSquadra),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print('snapshot: $snapshot');
          print('data: ${snapshot.data}');
          return Container();     
        });
```

EDIT: log for `print snapshot`:

```
snaphot: AsyncSnapshot<List<String>>(ConnectionState.active, null, type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>')
```

Comment: add `print('snapshot: $snapshot');` and post the logs

Comment: added the log @pskink

Comment: and `print('error: ${snapshot.error}');` - everything should be clear now

Comment: `error: type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' `. @pskink

Comment: that's why you have `null` in `snapshot.data` - seems like `return res` does not return a list of strings

Comment: How do I convert that MappedList to the List I need? I'm new to Flutter

Comment: `print('res: $res.runtimeType');` - what does it print?

Comment: It shows as `MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>`

Comment: `MappedListIterable`? never heard of..., hmm, does `return res.toList();` help?

Comment: Now the error is `error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'`. getting close I think, i'm now trying to give static types instead of using var

Comment: change to `return info.map<String>((i) => '...').toList();`

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot! If you post it as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: your welcome, write a self answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody needs this I found the problem thanks to pskink's advices. I was missing a type cast and a `toList()` call.

Correct code:

`return info.map<String>((i) => '...').toList();`